# Node Keystonejs unexpected token export/import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, keystonejs

I'm running this Keystonejs node webapp and I'm trying to include a class I created for my ReactNative project, but I'm getting the 'export' unexpected token error and I can't find how to fix that :\, I updated node to 6.2.0, I simply run it like `node keystone` I've tried the `node --harmony keystone` parameter but it still fails, I've tried installing the `babel-core babel-cli babel-preset-es2015` and nothing, I still can create a function with the `(arg) => { /*body*/}` form, although I don't even know in what version of ECMASCRIPT was that introduced xD. My class is declared just like that: `export default class API { ... }` API is my class name, and I intend to use it just like

`import API from "API";
  API.myMethod().then((res)=>{/*etc*/});`

Actually I get the unexpected token 'import' before I can get the export, I changed it to a 'require' instead, and then I get the export error (sorry I'm trying anything xD)
I'm working on mac, I built the keystone project with the `yo keystone` and I've set up my `mongod` just fine, the thing works well until I try to add my class, any help? plz :\

I also used the `async` and `await` keywords in my class methods and I think that may cause trouble too XD, specially because I saw the 'async' package on the package.json file :(, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because NodeJS has not implemented modules in version `6.20`. You can obtain a list of features that are being worked on by running the command:

```
node --v8-options | grep "in progress"
```

You should see this line:

> ```
> --harmony_modules (enable "harmony modules" (in progress))
> ```

To utilize modules (`import`, `export`), you'll need to use `babel` to compile your Javascript files in ES2015 to ES5. You can create a simple script to do this in your `package.json`:

```
"compile": "./node_modules/.bin/babel -d dist/ src/"
```

The script assumes you have `babel` installed.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your help! apparently it's compiling now, but I have another problem, I wonder if you could help me out with this one too xD inside my class I have multiple static objects declared like this `static myObject = {};` and now I'm getting an unexpected token `=` (although changing it to a `:` may be easier XD) thanks in advance :D

Comment: I dud its! XD, I did some more research on babel and compiling, and found out that I needed to use the es2015 and stage-0 presets, at first I didn't even knew what I was doing, now that I know that you don't just install babel, you actually have to compile your code with it xD it finally worked, now all I have to do is set up my work flow folders to compile and run the compiled code instead. Thanks a lot for your help @gnerkus !! :D